# Minimalist VideoCapture example produces a Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

A project I was working on suddenly started giving segmentation faults, even with a version I saved and knew was working.

I investigated a bit, and constructed a small example of what's happening :

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
  cv::VideoCapture capture("drop.avi");
  return 0;
}
```

According to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-videocapture), I should be able to do this :

> C++: VideoCapture::VideoCapture(const string& filename)

with

> filename – name of the opened video file (eg. video.avi) or image sequence

The following compilation command

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv` main.cpp
```

produces the executable without any warning.
However, when I execute the program :

```
./a.out 
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

According to users of the Interwebs, the issue could be related to `ffmpeg` and `opencv` having incompatible versions. The problem is, I don't see that documented anywhere, and I don't want to spend days compiling random versions of opencv, perhaps to no avail.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on ?

### Useful information

I am, of course, willing to provide any complementary information that would be needed.

#### Software versions

- Opencv2 2.4.13-1
- ffmpeg 1:3.1.3-1
- ffmpeg 2.8.7-3

(okay, so apparently I have two versions of ffmpeg ?)

#### System Information

- OS : Archlinux
- Linux kernel 4.7.2-1

Comment: ***the issue could be related to ffmpeg and opencv having incompatible versions.*** That would be my first guess. I would uninstall `ffmpeg 1:3.1.3-1` reinstall `ffmpeg 2.8.7-3` and do a clean opencv build.

Comment: @drescherjm I did, and it still segfault'ed (that's a word, right ?). So I did the next best thing, and changed the openCV version, and it works :)
Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by installing OpenCV 3.1